# What database uses these specific type of  .dat and .idx files?

Tags: database, schema

I'm trying to figure out what type of database uses these specific .dat and .idx files. When I view the .dat files using a binary file reader I see **Record Schema** followed by somewhat decipherable data names. A little further down I see **Key Schema** whch apears to be a comma separated list of clear text references.

Each .dat file has a matching .idx file. Each .dat file contains the phrase "Record Schema" and "Key Schema" as described above.

How would I convert these files so I can use them in an SQL database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[First search result](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Key+Schema+Record+Schema+idx+dat) returns it's an Informix database. Couldn't confirm it for you though.

Answer (score 0):

Should be Dbase, you can probably also open those with FoxPro, from within FoxPro you can `upsize` to SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

From memory it sounds like `Informix`

**or a tonque in cheek remark**

`Outlook Express` :)

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correcttly they are Paradox files. If they are, you should be able to access them via ODBC.

Comment: Paradox data files use .db as the file extension and don't have the strings "Record Schema" or "Key Schema" embedded in them.

Answer (score 0):

These are FairCom’s c-tree Plus database file.
And to read them in sql you need ODBC friver, below link explains it well.
http://dynamicsconfessions.blogspot.com/2010/07/using-odbc-to-read-on-line-field.html